# How to convert binary to decimal using a for loop?

Tags: python

I don't quite understand what I am doing wrong as I started learning Python 4 days back. I want to do this using for loop to convert binary number into decimal number.

```
def binary_to_decimal(number):
    i, integer = 0, 0
    size = list(number)
    for value in size:
        integer = int(size[i]) * pow(2, i)
        i += 1
    print(f"the decimal representation is {integer}")
def binary_to_decimal("111")
```

The output I am getting is 3 not 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to aggregate your variable integer using += instead of =

```
def binary_to_decimal(number):
    i, integer = 0, 0
    size = list(number)
    for value in size:
        integer += int(size[i]) * pow(2, len(size)-1-i)
        i += 1
    print(f"the decimal representation is {integer}")


>>> binary_to_decimal("111")
the decimal representation is 7
>>> bin(7)
'0b111'
```

Comment: **Thank you** @Ethan sir i understood my mistake

Comment: You are welcome. An up arrow and accepted answer would be appreciated.